# Unable to get a simple MVC web service to return a value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a very simple MVC web service and am getting a "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI XXXXXXXXXXX ." I have checked everything and can't figure out what is wrong. The url is correct because it works with other methods. Below is both the client and service:

Service

```
public class VersionController : ApiController
{
    private HttpResponseMessage response;

    /// <summary>
    /// Get application version.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {

      string myVersion = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Version"].ToString();

       response =  Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

       response.Content = new StringContent(myVersion, Encoding.Unicode, "application/json");

        return response;
    }
}
```

client

```
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string siteip = http://HABD-BI01/authservice/               

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(siteip);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

            response = client.GetAsync("Version").Result;

            string responseBodyAsText = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            ViewBag.Version = response.Content.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: what does your route table look like on the server? Have you tried hitting that endpoint with your browser?

Comment: Why in the world do you have a private ivar where you're storing the response for each action?